# codenameone Apps Error no virtual method

Tags: server, codenameone, floating-action-button

Hi I got this error No virtual method bindFabContainer(Lcom/codenamne1/uu/Container)

I use the desktop emulator it works perfectly. I sent it to buid in c1 cloud yesterday and it still works perfectly. but today i sent it again to build in c1 cloud server and got that error.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You built using the pre-released floating button implementation. Use the update client libraries option from the Codename One Settings and then send a new build. It should fix it by compiling against the new signature of the method.